# Как установить Windows на ноутбук, если ноутбук не видит сторонний монитор?

Tags: windows, железо, bios, ноутбук, монитор

Господа, есть ноут, у которого отсутствует ***( скорее не отсутствует, а я его сам удалил, так как, как мне рассказали, на него наступили... )***, дисплей...

Жесткий полностью очищен...

Так вот, далее подробнее о моих попытках...

Ноут, не видит монитор сторонний, вывода два  ***`VGA` и `HDMI`***.

Вставляю `загрузочную USB флешку`, подключаю к ***TV*** через `HDMI` и тишина. Черный экран логотип ***TV***, когда нет подключения. Мои скудные попытки вслепую запустить методом тыка не привели ни к какому результату... Тоже самое при подключении через `VGA` к монитору моего `PC`...

И тут я решаю попробовать установить ***`Ubuntu`***. Вставляю `загрузочную USB флешку`, пару тыков по клавише ***Enter*** и вуаля, вижу лого `Ubuntu` и далее минут ***10-ть*** лицезрел на штатную фоновую картинку `Ubuntu` пока не понял, что скорее всего  ноут в режиме расширенного монитора. Кликаю  ***`Fn-F4`*** и ***`ОООО чудо, вижу рабочий стол`***, далее устанавливаю систему. После установки cистема просит удалить `загрузочную USB флешку` и перезагрузиться...

После перезагрузки, вижу штатную фоновую картинку `Ubuntu`, но тут чудо не произошло, комбинация клавиш ***`Fn-F4`*** не дали ни каких результатов.... Ноут в режиме расширенного монитора...

Кто подскажет, что можно сделать с этим чудом техники от ***SAMSUNG***?
Как сделать так, чтобы подключить сторонний монитор и при этом он работал в режиме `BIOS`?

> BIOS Уже сбрасывал...

Comment: Если он в сети, то попробуйте подключится с другого компа. Получится, пробуйте с настройками х, чтобы vga главным выходом был. Или с загрузочной флешки и change root, как обычно.

Comment: Внимательнее читать вопросы надо...

Comment: Извините, а что я там пропустил?

Comment: Пустой винчестер... Научите меня, как не видя ничего на мониторе можно что-то сделать...  с меня магарыч))))

Comment: "После установки cистема просит удалить загрузочную USB флешку и перезагрузиться" - а куда вы систему установили, если винт пустой?

Comment: Да но я не могу ничего делать, на мониторе розовый фон...  Как мне к сетке подключиться?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86123/discussion-between-air-and-0xdb).

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант вытащить диск, поставить систему с другого компа, не ставя спец. драйверов и установить диск обратно. После попытаться fn-F4.

Для убунты надо отключить lvds - это встроенный монитор. Мне помогала команда:

```
sudo -u lightdm -H DISPLAY=":0.0" --xrandr --output LVDS1 -off
```

Comment: Уже, но увы...  Но без проблем установил `Mint`...